# How can I convert from table a to table b in SQL

Tags: sql, hive

Table a:

```
Name    Channel  score
-----------------------
Suresh   Web      100
Suresh   App       50
```

Table b:

```
Name     Web   App
-----------------------
Suresh   100    50
```

I want to know a way in SQL to do so. I want to transform the category values of column channel with the respective values associated with it in score. Basically like a transform

Comment: Have a look for conditional aggregation

Comment: or possibly PIVOT

Answer (score 0):

```
select Name, App, Web
from MyTable a
pivot (max(score) for channel in ([App],[Web])) p
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**